What barriers to the public internet do police have that citizens do not?
The Guardian reports in reference to police action against the far right instigators of the recent violence:

The strict rules on evidence gathering for police and government bodies made it harder for authorities to scour some parts of the internet that are public, [Adam Hadley, the executive director of Tech Against Terrorism] said.
“What we’ve been trying to do is fill the gap between the government and the platforms. There are all sorts of perhaps unexpected barriers to doing things that are quite easy for us to do as citizens.”

What are these strict rules and barriers?

Jurisdiction is the key here. A .de page is supposedly hosted in germany, a .at in Austria and a .com could be just about anywhere.

I do not understand this.  Are you saying the UK police could be prevented from accessing data at the .de domain that is available to the general public?

@User65535 accessing data on the domain is easy, proving who posted what and hosted what is much harder.

@Trish, I believe you are mixing two different problems. One is the question where a site is hosted (only marginally related to the domain name). This matters when the police need a warrant to get non-public information from the operator. The other question is how the police can collect and analyze publicly available information. In a democracy, there are usually regulations what sort of files the police can have on their citizens and how they are combined. The latter seems to be the issue here.

I can follow all your Facebook and Twitter posts. The police can’t without a warrant.

@gnasher729 The law behind that would be an answer.

@o.m. UK police can't just get a warrant for a server in Germany, they'd first have to request assistance from the German police, who in turn have to file for a warrant.

@Trish The general public cannot "just get a warrant for a server in Germany" either.  The question is what would they have to get a warrant for that the general public could just do?  From the comments it may be something like the Sun Journalist who sat in on the Just Stop Oil zoom call, and if so that would be the answer.

I suspect this is the opposite problem. Police may have to get a warrant to search internet sites (if they want to be able to use the evidence in court), while ordinary citizens are not so restricted.

@gnasher729, depending on privacy settings, you may only be able to follow someone if you are accepted as a "friend". And if privacy settings allow full access to the public, then why couldn't a cop follow someone?
